# Is there any way to solve NODE createReadSream error ENOENT: no such file or directory with fs.unlink?

Tags: node.js, macos, ubuntu

### Goal

1. check file is exists
2. if a file exists delete that

Here is stand-alone test code

```
const fs = require("fs")

const fileName = "a.txt"

fs.writeFile(fileName, "Hello World", function () { })

fs.createReadStream(fileName) // error!

fs.unlink(fileName, function (err) {
  if(err) console.error(err, "err")
})
```

It works on `MacOS` with `node v12.13.0` but not working on `MacOS` `node v16.13.0` and `Ubuntu20.04.3 LTS` with `node v12.13.0, v16.13.0`

I know that not a good idea to use `createReadStream` for files exists but I'd want to know what's wrong with it.

And here is my revised code.

### version1. using createReadStream

```
const file = fs.createReadStream(filePath)

file.on('end', () => {
  fs.unlink(filePath, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error(err, "err")
  })
})
```

### version2. using existsSync

```
if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
  fs.unlinkSync(filePath)
}
```

---

### Question

What is the problem, why MacOS v12.13.0 works but MacOS v16.13.0. and Why not working on Ubuntu

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `writeFile` is an async operation. It might be that on a OS/Node combination it takes longer to actually write that file so that the rest of your code just fails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, Johnny. `writeFile` code for a standalone code without any settings.

Then how about this code without `writeFile`

```javascript
const fs = require("fs")

const fileName = "a.txt"

fs.createReadStream(fileName) // error!

fs.unlink(fileName, function (err) {
  if(err) console.error(err, "err")
})
```
Is this error because of the same reason(async function `createReadStream`)?